# ListView of a Fragment (of a ViewPager inside a Fragment) that implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> is empty when I return back to it

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, loader

The ListView inside of a Fragment that contains a ViewPager is empty when I return back to it. This ViewPager is inside of a Fragment because I'm using a Navigation Drawer Layout. I'll try to explain it in more details now:

I am using a Navigation Drawer layout and, consequently, using Fragments. In the main activity, in onCreate, I set the current Fragment with these lines of code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    /* More code */

    currentFragment = new MainFragment();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.layout_for_fragments, currentFragment).commit();
}
```

The MainFragment class contains a ViewPager that is initialized with these lines of code in the onCreateView():

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    /* More code */

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.main_view_pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new SimpleFragmentPagerAdapter(getActivity(), getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()));

    /* Code for Tablayout */

    return rootView;
}
```

One of the Fragments of the SimpleFragmentPagerAdapter class is this one that implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks

```
public class ExpensesFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private ExpenseCursorAdapter mExpenseCursorAdapter;

    private static final int EXPENSE_LOADER = 1;

    public ExpensesFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_expenses, container, false);

        ListView expensesListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.expenses_list_view);
        mExpenseCursorAdapter = new ExpenseCursorAdapter(getContext(), null);
        expensesListView.setAdapter(mExpenseCursorAdapter);

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(EXPENSE_LOADER, null, this);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new CursorLoader(/* arguments */);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        mExpenseCursorAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        mExpenseCursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
}
```

On the first run, everything works fine. However, if I click on the navigation drawer menu, which I'm implementing this way, the ListView becomes empty:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_main) {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(currentFragment).commit();

        currentFragment = new MainFragment();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.layout_for_fragments, currentFragment).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_blank) {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(currentFragment).commit();

        currentFragment = new BlankFragment();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.layout_for_fragments, currentFragment).commit();

    }

    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

The problem also exists when I rotate the device. There is a difference though. When I use the Navigation Drawer menu, none of the methods of the LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks are called, but when I rotate the device, onLoadFinished is called.

Anyway, the problem persists. Any ideias how to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution!

Basically, I made two mistakes.
The first one is about the rotation of the device. 
When the device is rotated, the Activity is destroyed and onCreate is called again. In this case, I should't call new MainFragment(). So, I check if the savedInstanceState is null before I call it, like this:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    currentFragment = new MainFragment();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().
            replace(R.id.layout_for_fragments, currentFragment).commit();
}
```

The second one is about a fragment within a fragment. In this case, I can't simply call getSupportFragmentManager(). I should call getChildFragmentManager() instead and that's it!